# Is this limit correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

In $\mathbb R$, Suppose $\{x_n\}\to 0 $ and $\{y_n\}$ is bounded.
In order to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_ny_n=0$, I proved:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}|x_ny_n|\leq M\lim_{n\to\infty}x=0$, and conclude the limit without absolute value exists, Is it correct?

Comment: Missing some symbols, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what machinery (in the way of prior theorems) is available to you. We solve the problem in detail, using only the definition.

We want to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_ny_n=0$. So we want to show that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|x_ny_n -0|\lt \epsilon$. Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

Since the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is bounded, there exists an $M$ such that $|y_n|\lt M$ for all $n$. We may without loss of generality assume that $M\gt 0$.

Since the sequence $\{x_n\}$ has limit $0$, there is an $N$ such that $|x_n|\lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{M}$ if $n\gt N$.

Thus if $n\gt N$, we have
$$|x_ny_n| \le |x_n| M \lt \dfrac{\epsilon}{M} =\epsilon.$$

**Remark:** The basic programs for a computer need to be written in machine language, and can be quite tedious to write.  After a while, instead of going back to machine language each time, we produce a collection of  *subroutines* that can be called on. The basic limit theorems are such subroutines. Once these are available, we can much of the time call on them, instead of returning to $\epsilon$-$\delta$ or $\epsilon$-$N$ each time.

Your solution used (correctly) several such results. Suppose that $\lim x_n$ exists and $|y_n|\le M$. It is quite possible that the (correct and intuitively reasonable) result that $\lim|x_ny_n|\le M\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|$ has in fact **not** been proved in your course. In that case, there would be a formal gap in your argument.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah the proof is correct if you say that $M$ is a bound of $y_n.$ 
For a more formal proof you can say: 
$$ - M |x_n|\leq  y_n |x_n| \leq M |x_n| $$
and with the sandwich theorem you have the convergence.

Comment: In English, better to say $M$ is a bound (not boundary) of $|y_n|$.